# How to get remote access of datanodes in Apache IoTDB when local access is fine

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone encountered the problem that there is no problem with local access, but cannot successfully execute remote access of data nodes in Apache IoTDB? I checked the server's firewalls are all turned off, and the network to this data node is successfully connected. I checked the official guide and tried to change the IP to 0.0.0.0, but it does not seem to solve the problem. What else could be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this may be caused by the configuration problem of datanode. The rpc address needs to be added in Apache IoTDB. You can add it to the file `iotdb-datanode.properties`.